# Set Different Color Palettes for Different Layers in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the trajectory of an animal moving through an arena. I want to plot both a heat map of the entire arena AND the actual trajectory of the animal. For the trajectory, I want the path to be color coded by how fast the animal was moving at each given point.

Example Data:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(frame = seq(1,50,1),
             x = c(51.34564, 52.02254, 52.60115, 53.20906, 53.88028, 54.55151, 55.13741, 55.41307, 56.08957,
             56.68501, 57.28044, 57.62111, 58.13888, 58.38356, 58.38356, 58.38356, 58.17859, 57.52251,
             56.86643, 56.21035, 55.55427, 54.89819, 54.54640, 54.19461, 53.85371, 53.51281, 53.01192,
             52.51103, 51.82817, 51.14532, 50.46246, 49.82272, 49.18298, 48.38321, 47.58344, 46.78368,
             45.98391, 45.18414, 44.38437, 43.55679, 42.78776, 42.02832, 41.24797, 40.38921, 39.67093,
             38.78841, 38.07554, 37.04552, 36.21359, 35.42233),
             y = c(93.59669,  93.82952,  94.02557,  94.15208,  94.44488,  94.73768,  95.12280,  95.37992,
                   95.68827,  95.97229,  96.25632,  96.38436,  96.71693,  96.98220,  97.23499,  97.48778,
                   97.84184,  98.40484,  98.96784,  99.53085, 100.09385, 100.65685, 101.04628,  101.43570,
                   101.85187, 102.26803, 102.85582, 103.44360, 104.01978, 104.59596, 105.17213, 105.76429,
                   106.35644, 106.09024, 105.82403, 105.55783, 105.29163, 105.02542, 104.75922, 104.44431,
                   104.13191, 103.54044, 103.15739, 102.96974, 102.55943, 101.98391, 101.39337, 101.03815,
                   100.69386, 100.23876),
             speed = runif(100, min=0, max=5))
```

I'm able to create the background heat map using stat_density2d, in the color palette that I want. However, when I try to overlay the trajectory (using geom_path), I'm unable to customize the color of that layer.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
       xlab('X') + 
       ylab('Y') +
       stat_density2d(aes(fill=after_stat(density)), contour=FALSE, geom="raster", data=df) +
       scale_fill_distiller(palette="BuGn", direction=-1) +
       geom_path(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=speed), size=1) +
       theme_classic()
```

Which produces this: [plot of time density and trajectory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z73I.png)

As you can see, the trajectory color coding is not very useful for seeing variation in speed. How can I change this color scheme, while keeping the stat density color scheme the way it is currently is? Preferably this would be using a built in color scheme (such as distiller/brewer used for the density portion), but options for custom gradient are also welcome.

Comment: you can add a color palette e.g., `+ scale_color_distiller("BrBG")`

Comment: To have different palettes for different layers (two different color scales), I think you have options: (1) try to use multiple scales with 3rd-party apps like `ggnewscale` or `relayer`; (2) transform the data so that both the data feeding the heatmap and feeding the trail are handled by the same palette but by non-overlapping regions. The latter is a bit hacky ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation is convenient that one layer is "fill" and the other layer is "color". Adding a continuous color scale such as `scale_color_viridis_c()` or  `scale_color_distiller()` should solve this problem:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  xlab('X') + ylab('Y') +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=after_stat(density)), contour=FALSE, geom="raster") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="BuGn", direction=-1) +
  geom_path(aes(color=speed), size=1) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_viridis_c() # <-------------------------------------
  #scale_color_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd", direction=-1)
```

[image: example with scale_color_viridis_c function]

Comment: Yep, that does it! Thanks!

Comment: @alyb_batgirl PS. You can remove the redundent `data=df` and the extra `x=x...` code, Those are assigned in the main `ggplot()` call. See my edit. FYI